# how can I use a particular regex with glob

Tags: python, regex, glob

I have a folder called example and it has several folders in it like ABC, BC, ABCD, etc. Folder name varies from 2-4 letters. in each folder, it has different files. For ABCD, it has ABCD-circle.txt, ABCD-circle-square.txt, ABCD-square.txt.
same for other folders like for BC, it has BC-circle.txt,BC-circle-square.txt, BC-square.txt.

I want to get only the circle.txt for each folder i.e. ABCD-circle.txt, BC-circle.txt.

I tried using glob path in python

```
local =  glob.glob('/Users/tp/Downloads/example/*/[A-Z]*-circle.txt')
```

but here I am getting all files BC-circle.txt,BC-circle-square.txt,ABCD-circle.txt,ABCD-circle-square.txt.

and if I do

```
  local =  glob.glob('/Users/tp/Downloads/example/*/[A-Z]{2,4}-circle.txt')
```

then I am getting nothing.
Please advice!!

Comment: Regex != glob...

Comment: I know But I want to find some files with unique patterns using glob

Comment: 1) Do a glob that captures all the `*circle.txt` files you want and including false matches; 2) Filter the results of that glob to exactly what you want. That second filtering step can be by regex if you wish. `[fn for fn in glob.glob('/Users/tp/Downloads/example/*/[A-Z]*-circle.txt') if re.search(r'your_regex')]` or something like that...

Comment: "The glob module finds all the pathnames matching a specified pattern according to the rules used by the Unix shell" in https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the following:

```
local =  glob.glob('/Users/tp/Downloads/example/*/[A-Z]*-circle.txt')
for filePath in local:
    matches = re.findall("[A-Z]{2,4}-circle.txt", filePath)
    if matches:
        print(filePath)
```

and that worked!